# Wolfram Alpha functions and plots

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

I am new with wolfram alpha and I am trying to do the following but I am having trouble doing it.

(1) On Wolfram Alpha, how can we plot two inequalities on the same graph? For example, if I want to plot x^3>-1 and x^2 - 1 < 0

(2) On Wolfram Alpha, how can we use the If function to impose restrictions on variables. For example, I want to ask "If x>0, is 4^x < 3 ^(x+1) ? How do I impose the constraint "x>0"?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about Wolfram Alpha usage and has nothing to do with programming. Please see [ask] about the topics you can ask here.

Comment: @0stone0 He's clearly trying to program Wolfram Alpha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one:

```
solve x^3 > -1 && x^2 - 1 < 0
```

> -1 < x < 1

Second one:

```
4^x < 3^(x + 1) && x > 0
```

> (0, -log(3)/(log(3) - 2 log(2))

I.e. true between 0 and 3.81884

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !! Do you also know how I can ask Wolfram Alpha “Is a^b * b > 0 if |a|=b && ab<0?”. Basically I want to know if a relationship is always true given two constraints.

Comment: Same as Mathematica input: `Refine[a^b b > 0,{Abs[a]==b, a b < 0}]`

Comment: Thank you so much !!! Do you also know how I can define my variables as even/odd integers or just integers? Using a basic example: How would I write on Wolfram Alpha: 3y^2 + 7y = x if x = integer and y = odd integer? Do you also know how I can write x = prime number? Thank you!

Comment: In Mathematica this could be confirmed by `Resolve[Exists[{x, y}, 3 y^2 + 7 y == x && Mod[y, 2] != 0], Integers]` - nod to [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/615/363).  Can't say for Alpha.